# Latex: How can I create nested lists which look this 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2 

Tags: list, latex

How can I create lists which look this:

```
1. Topic
1.1 First Subtopic
1.2 Second Subtopic
```

I tried using the enumeration list

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Topic
\begin{enumerate}
\item First Subtopic
\item Second Subtopic
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

But the output looks like:

```
1. Topic
  (a) First Subtopic
  (b) Second Subtopic
```

So how can I get the list? Is there another list evironment or maybe an extra package?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Topic
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
    \item First Subtopic
    \item Second Subtopic
    \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
      \item First Sub-Subtopic
      \item Second Sub-Subtopic
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

See the [catalog entry for enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) for more.

Comment: How do I make it work for 2nd level of nesting - like 1.1.1? Right now, I have like 1.11 and 1.12 when going to 2nd level.

Comment: @bikashg: I have updated my example.  The old one had a bug in it :-)

Comment: The key here is the `*=` in `[label*=\arabic*.]`. If omitted, the list will restarted and you won't get 1.1, 1.2 etc.

Comment: @AlokSinghal  Your link is broken.

Answer (score 19):

See: http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/latex/ltx-222.html

> The numbering style for the enumeration is determined by the commands, \labelenumi, \labelenumii, etc., for the nested levels. These may be redefined with the \renewcommand command.
>
> For example, to use upper case letters for the first level and lower case letters for the second level of enumeration:

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\Alph{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\alph{enumii}}
```

And here: [http://www.mackichan.com/index.html?techtalk/484.htm~mainFrame](http://www.mackichan.com/index.html?techtalk/484.htm%7EmainFrame)

... The concrete commands would be

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.} 
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}
```

Or, if you think your content qualifies as sections, use something like:

```
\section{Name}
...
\subsection{Subtopic}
...
\subsubsection{Yet another nesting}
...
```

Comment: The concrete commands would be `\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}` and `\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}`.

Answer (score 7):

No need to use any additional package

```
\begin{enumerate}
   \item[1.] Topic
   \begin{enumerate}
       \item[1.1] First Subtopic
       \item[1.2] Second Subtopic
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Although this approach is manual, I think it serves best, for a singular occurrence of such a list. If you need it more than once, then I would go with enumitem as described above. However, take care when you reorganize such lists, to adapt the labels to the new ordering.